# Chain rule with two parameterizations

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I am trying to understand how to apply the chain rule.  Suppose that I have a sufficiently smooth real valued function of two real variables $w(x,y)$.

Let us say that we also have a change of variables $(x,y) = F(\hat{x},\hat{y})$, and we define $\hat{w} = w \circ F$.  In this case, I know that the chain rule gives us
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \hat{w}}{\partial \hat{x}   }\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \hat{w}}{\partial \hat{y}}\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial x}.
$$

Now, I want to assume that $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are both functions of a variable $s$.  Say, $(\hat{x},\hat{y})=(\gamma_1(s),\gamma_2(s))$.  In this situation, how can I compute $ \frac{\partial [w\circ F \circ (\gamma_1(s),\gamma_2(s))]}{\partial x}$?

**EDIT:**  The comment below says I should examine the Jacobain matrices.  So, for the first case we would have
$$
\bigg[\frac{\partial w}{\partial x},\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\bigg]
=
\bigg[\frac{\partial \hat{w}}{\partial \hat{x}},\frac{\partial \hat{w}}{\partial \hat{y}}\bigg] 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial y}
\\
\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix} .
$$
It is still not clear to me what the Jacobian for the second mapping would be.  Is it $[\frac{\partial s}{\partial \hat{x}},\frac{\partial s}{\partial \hat{y}}]^T$?

Comment: Once things go beyond a simple composition of two functions I find it easier to compute the individual Jacobian matrices and multiply them together, then pick out the required elements instead of trying to slog through multiple levels of cumbersome notation.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean in an answer?  I am not exactly sure what is meant by this.

Comment: Do you know what the Jacobian is?

Comment: I edited my post, but I'm still unsure about multiplying the individual Jacobian matrices.   The dimensions do not seem to match correctly.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You can't differentiate a function of $s$ *only* with respect to $x$, $y$, or anything else. You should be asking about the derivative with respect to $s$.

Comment: Double-check what you’ve written down for the Jacobians. If you multiply out the right-hand side, you don’t get the correct result.

Comment: Looks like I need to take the transpose of the 2x2 Jacobian?  But one of the other commenters says my question makes no sense.  I'm confused.

Comment: The question does make sense, since $s$ implicitly depend on $x$ and $y$ I think. You have something like $F^{-1}(x,y) = (\gamma_1(s),\gamma_2(s))$. So notice that the total differential of $w$ should be the same as the total differential of the expression you looking for (that depends on s). Both should give you a $1\times2$ jacobian where you should be able to read of the desired expression. Maybe think about the right hand side like $(\hat w \circ \gamma)(s)$ where $\gamma = (\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$ and apply chain rule a couple of times.

Comment: I think I am still running in some trouble here. I think everything works fine if you would consider a second parameterization that also depends on two variables.